# Use apply function without return

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I have an array like this: 1:4; i would use write function the same times as the length of the array.

```
 apply(1:4,2,function(i){
         example <- functionexample(i)
         write.table(example, file="C:\\Users\\example")
        }
```

Are there other functions ? I wouldn't use for loop. Using apply return an error:  dim(X) must have a positive length.

Comment: this is exactly what `for` is for. Why not use it?

Comment: Because apply fuctions (lapply,sapply,..) are better internally implemented

Comment: That is not true.  They are wrappers around a `for` loop

Comment: use `lapply(1:4, function(x)...`

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::walk(.x, .f)` will apply a function, `.f` to all elements of `.x` without returning anything.

Answer (score -1):

`apply` is used for the matrices and arrays, for atomice vector `1:4` you can use `lapply`. Please see below a code which will create four csv files with random content:

```
functionexample <- function(i) {
  data.frame(x = sample(10), y = rnorm(10))
}

lapply(1:4, function(i){
  example <- functionexample(i)
  write.table(example, file = paste0("example", i, ".csv", sep = ""))
})
```